# How to terminate a background (nohup) Mathematica parallel process in terminal?

Tags: linux

I'm running a Mathematica code on a remote computer in parallel, by using
`nohup`command. It seems that there is a problem in the code and I need to stop it. Since it is working in background, `Ctrl+c` is not working to terminate it. using `top` command, I found `PID` for the 16 cores that I am using, but `Kill PID` doesn't stop the MathematicaKernel. Is there anything else I can do?

Edit: 
According to rakuo15's answer at https://superuser.com/questions/161531/how-to-kill-all-processes-in-linux , I forced every process to stop by using `killall5 -9`. It stopped the MathematicaKernel plus everything else. If there is a better way, it would be great to know.

Comment: Does `kill -9 PID` work? Be aware that it might crash your main kernel as well if communication is unexpectedly killed.

Comment: no I also tried that. but the cpu was still working for the MathematicaKernel.
Actually I noticed if I `kill PID`, that special `PID` is killed, but replaced with another `PID` and the number of running cores is not changed.